# uiscrollview in uiview not scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I am using the storyboard to create a `UIView` that contains a `UIScrollView` that has many child items in it.  these child items consist of a `UIImageView` that I am using as a background image for the `UIScrollView`, a series of `UILabels` that I populate programmatically, and a series of `UITableViews` that I populate with data obtained from a called set of library classes.  I want all of this in my `UIScrollView` so the User can scroll through all of the information without having multiple views being displayed.  I have browsed through a lot of postings here and have used a lot of the suggestions, but have been unable to successfully have the view scroll and allow the user to see all the data I'm attempting to present.

Here's a screen shot of the Storyboard followed by a shot of the attribute inspector for my `UIScrollView`

[image]

[image]

I'll also provide the .h and .m files

weatherController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WeatherParser.h"
#import "WeatherLocation.h"
#import "WeatherImg.h"
#import "WeatherWind.h"
#import "ForcastDay.h"
#import "ForecastItem.h"
#import "Condition.h"
#import "Atmo.h"
#import "Astro.h"
@class WeatherParser;
@class WeatherParserDelegate;
@class WeatherLocation;
@class WeatherImg;
@class WeatherWind;
@class ForcastDay;
@class ForecastItem;
@class Condition;
@class Atmo;
@class Astro;

@interface weatherController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,WeatherParserDelegate>{
    WeatherParser * _rssParser;
    bool loadingEvents;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) WeatherParser * rssParser;
@property bool loadingEvents;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cityLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *state_countryLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *currHighLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *currLowLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *currTempLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *logoImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *logoLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *forecastTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *atmoTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *windTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *astroTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *forecastDays;
@property bool logoSet;

@end
```

and here's my weatherController.m file.  I'm going to only add the `viewDidLoad` method which is the only method containing code regarding my `UIScrollView`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _scrollView.delegate = self;    

//    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f, 480.0f);
    self.scrollView.contentSize =CGSizeMake(320.0F, 480.0F);  //(320, 1210)];
    [_scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

I would appreciate any help regarding what it is I'm either doing wrong or missing.  If I set up my `frame` and `contentSize` to the following:

```
self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0f, 480.0f);
self.scrollView.contentSize =CGSizeMake(320.0F, 1210.0F);
```

I do get the `UIScrollView` to scroll, but the image for the background is only the size of the frame, and none of the rest of the child content on the `UIScrollView` is displayed.  It seems like it's allowing me to scroll but I'm only able to view the content that is viewable within the `frame`.

Again, thank you in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Why are you putting tableViews in scrollViews?!

Comment: @paulrehkugler it's an easy and efficient way of displaying information that would be displayed in a table like fashion regardless of tableViews being used or not.  Besides, the tables are only 3-5 rows long. they aren't big and won't take up much space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments are suggesting, it's generally a bad idea to put a UITableView within a UIScrollView. I won't be too hard on you though, because there is a time and place where it is an acceptable solution. I'll let you judge if this time is now or not.

For reasons I still don't fully understand, UIScrollView behaves more like you expect it to if you enclose the entire contents in a single UIView that is as big as you want the UIScrollView to scroll.

Comment: Placing all of my content into a `UIView` and then placing that `UIView` into my `UIScrollView` resolved all the trouble I was having.  I will also take the `UITableView` inside the `UIScrollView` under advisement and seriously think it over.  Thank you very much.