# Unable to scroll in scroll view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

This is my view layout in storybaord:

[image]

My Scroll view frame is set to be `320x568`, and in my view controller I have set

```
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,1000)];//obviously content is larger than frame
```

However, the scroll still doesn't work. So I enabled vertical bounce, and found that every time when I drag down it just bounces back to original position. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: One possible problem would be that you forgot to link that object in Layout manager to your 'scrollView' property.

Comment: @manecosta I did, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Create a breakpoint at those lines to make sure the code is being ran and that 'scrollView' is not null.

Comment: @manecosta I did, and scrollView is not nil or null.

Comment: Well, we must be missing something but as far as I can remember, a scrollView will scroll when the contentSize is bigger than its frame. The only thing I can think of would be Paging.. Do you have paging enabled? I'm not sure the scrollView would scroll if the content isn't big enough for at least 2 pages, which it isn't.

Comment: @manecosta I tried to set the height to 2000 with both paging enabled and disabled, and neither works.

Comment: Set the content size to the size of the subview

Comment: Is that all your relevant code? I bet maybe you keep adding subviews programmatically to the scrollview without changing the `contenSize`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First turn off AutoLayout - click on scrollview and uncheck Use AutoLayout

In your .h file add the UIScrollViewDelegate for example:

`@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>`

In your .m file in viewDidLoad set

```
self.myScrollView.delegate = self;
self.myscrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.myscrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320.0, 1094.0);
```

keep Bounces ON and set scrollview frame 320 X 960

Answer (score 0):

In your .h file add the `UIScrollViewDelegate` for example:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

In your .m file in viewDidLoad set

```
self.myScrollView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I don't think that the delegate property needs to be set for the scrollview to correctly scroll.

Comment: Try setting the scrollview frame also programmatically because you may have autorisizing rules and constraints that resize it. `scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];`

Comment: @NikosM. No it doesn't work either, even with explicit settings.

Comment: set this also in the viewDidLoad `[myScrollView setClipsToBounds: YES];`

Answer (score 0):

If you have one subview in your scrollview, as you do, the scrollview will scroll to the dimensions of that view. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457395/uiscrollview-in-uiview-not-scrolling) for details.

Answer (score 0):

view.userInteractionEnabled = YES